# Существующие инструменты REST API для работы с криптовалютой

Tags: криптография, поиск-api, криптовалюта, currency

мне нужны все криптовалюты с их курсами. История изменений мне не нужна. Нашёл только https://rapidapi.com/minerstat/api/mineable-coins/
но в ней нет фиата. Подскажите пожалуйста открытые API для того, чтобы получать курсы криптовалют

Comment: Желательно может кто то знает апи с курсом валют и криптовалют

Comment: Идентичный вопрос. Зачем плодите дубликаты? ) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1513074

Answer (score 0):

Классика жанра - [coinbase](https://help.coinbase.com/en/cloud/api/coinbase), на крайний случай попробуйте bitquery и quickNode

вот пример,если что это просто на f12 я запрос с сайта посмотрел, я не знаю можно ли таким пользоваться, дайте комментарий

ответ примерно такой :

```
{
  "data": {
    "btc": {
      "slug": "bitcoin",
      "symbol": "BTC",
      "name": "Bitcoin",
      "imageUrl": "https://dynamic-assets.coinbase.com/e785e0181f1a23a30d9476038d9be91e9f6c63959b538eabbc51a1abc8898940383291eede695c3b8dfaa1829a9b57f5a2d0a16b0523580346c6b8fab67af14b/asset_icons/b57ac673f06a4b0338a596817eb0a50ce16e2059f327dc117744449a47915cb2.png",
      "latestQuote": {
        "price": "2479426.3641772726740945203943717020544",
        "quoteCurrency": "RUB"
      },
```

Comment: Я не очень понял что вы получаете в примере

Comment: @Takeda делаете такой гет запрос , вам приходит json, вы его парсите, получаете оттуда текущую цену разной крипты в рублях